# LIMIT N vs TOP N in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am starting to use SQL Server. The following works:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM SalesRawData 
WHERE Title = N'Sriracha'
```

But the following causes an error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SalesRawData 
WHERE Title = N'Sriracha' 
LIMIT 100
```

Why can't I use the "normal" limit syntax at the end here?

Comment: @Shadow I see -- so actually there's no such thing as a limit in sql-server. Correct?

Comment: Because tsql does not support the limit clsuse, it supports the top clause.

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't the "normal" way of doing this - it's the **MySQL** (and Postgres) **specific** way of handling getting only a few rows. Sybase chose to use `SELECT TOP...` in T-SQL instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DMBS vendors have proprietary syntax to provide `LIMIT` functionality. A [draft of the ANSI/ISO standards](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30452/ansi-iso-plans-for-limit-standardization) allows a `OFFSET` and `FETCH` clauses, which is also implemented in SQL Server. `ORDER BY` is required (and with TOP also) to provide predictable results.

Below is an alternative:

```
SELECT * FROM SalesRawData
WHERE Title = N'Sriracha' 
ORDER BY Title OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server supports two ways to limit the number of results returned from a query. The simplest is `TOP`, which you have already discovered. The more advanced is `FETCH`, which also allows for specifying an offset to implement paging. Written using the `FETCH` method, your query would be `SELECT * FROM SalesRawData where Title = N'Sriracha' OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY`. You can find the documentation for `TOP` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and the documentation for `FETCH` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).